# Как объединить 3 столбца в один?

Tags: python, pandas

```
5   math score                   1000 non-null   int64 
6   reading score                1000 non-null   int64 
7   writing score                1000 non-null   int64
```

Надо объединить эти 3 столбца в один

```
0      72
1      69
2      90
3      47
4      76
```

То что находится в них

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. столбцы чего? где в вопросе три столбца? как объединить?

Comment: @strawdog Они там горизонтально лежат ))

Answer (score 1):

Просто сложите столбцы:

```
df['total score'] = df['math score'] + df['reading score'] + df['writing score']
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант решения:

```
cols = ["math score", "reading score", "writing score"]
df["total score"] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
```